# Greatest prime factor of $\left(\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2-1$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Consider
$$
\left(\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2-1.
$$
Is is possible to say something about the lower bound on the greatest prime divisor of the above expression depending only on $n$? I surfed through some articles and sites on the internet but have not managed to find anything about this concrete situation.

Obviously, we can write it as
$$
\left(\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}+1\right)\left(\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}-1\right).
$$
It is also evident that the greatest common divisor of these two terms can be at most $2$. I do not know if this help, but at least we can say that the greatest prime divisor divides exactly one of these terms...

Also it is one less then the square of a triangular number. I added both elementary and standard number theory as tags, because I am not able to decide the hardness of the problem.

Comment: Note that the second term factors further into $(n-1)(n+2)/2$.  But it is still a hard problem in general.  Have you tried http://www.math.ubc.ca/~gerg/papers/downloads/PVFLPF.pdf as a reference?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I will take a look in a moment.

Comment: See also the first page of https://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1976-27.pdf.  Showing that there are only finitely many $n$ where all the prime factors of $P(n)$ are less than $k$ follows fairly easily from Siegel's theorem on integer points on curves (so that one does have a non-constant lower bound).  But it wasn't made effective until Baker's theorem, and even then the lower bound is only $O(\log \log n)$, at least in 1976.